# How to fix overlay issues in three.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, three.js

I´m trying to render an `iframe` with the `CSS3DRenderer` of `three.js` in Angular.

Now im facing the problem, that i´m not able to click anything in the content (no pointer events).
I seem that the reason is the overlayed webgl `<div id="webgl">`.

Whenever i change the order of the two div´s `<div id="css3d">` and  `<div id="webgl">`, the `CSS3DObject` cover the other content and does not get attached to the box, where i want it to be redered.

Order:

`<div id="css3d">` 
`<div id="webgl">`

[image]

Order:

`<div id="webgl">` 
`<div id="css3d">`

[image]

This is how i init the CSS3DRenderer:

```js
private _init3DRenderer()
    {
        this._3DRenderer = new CSS3DRenderer();
        this._3DRenderer.setSize(this.css3dContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth, this.css3dContainer.nativeElement.clientHeight);
        this.css3dContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(this._3DRenderer.domElement);
    }
```

as well as initializing the WebGlRenderer:

```js
private _initRenderer()
    {
        this._renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
        this._renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        this._renderer.setSize(this.webglContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth, this.webglContainer.nativeElement.clientHeight);
        this._renderer.outputEncoding = sRGBEncoding;
        this._renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        this._renderer.shadowMap.type = PCFSoftShadowMap;
        this.webglContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(this._renderer.domElement);
    }
```

after initialization im adding an object to the WebG as well as the iframe.

```js
        const obj = new Object3D();
        let css3dObject = new CSS3DObject(iframe);
        obj.add(css3dObject)


        // make an invisible plane for the DOM element to chop
        // clip a WebGL geometry with it.
        var material = new MeshPhongMaterial({
            opacity: 0.1,
            color: new Color(0x000001),
            blending: NoBlending,
            side: DoubleSide,
        });
        var geometry = new BoxGeometry(width, height, 30);
        var mesh = new Mesh(geometry, material);
        // mesh.castShadow = true;
        mesh.receiveShadow = true;
        // obj.lightShadowMesh = mesh
        obj.add(mesh);
```

the  different renderer sharing the same scene:

```js
private _render()
    {
        this._renderer?.render(this._scene, this._camera);
        this._3DRenderer?.render(this._scene, this._camera);
    }
```

html template

```html
<div (window:resize)="onWindowResize($event)"
     #webglContainer
     style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">
</div>
<div #css3dContainer
     style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. CSS for the webgl div:

```css
    pointer-events: none;
```